# Httpclient This instance has already started one or more requests. Properties can only be modified before sending the first request

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpclient, asp.net-core-2.0, dotnet-httpclient

I am creating an application in .Net Core 2.1 and I am using http client for web requests. The issue is I have to send parallel calls to save time and for that I am using Task.WhenAll() method but when I hit this method I get the error "This instance has already started one or more requests. Properties can only be modified before sending the first request" Previously I was using RestSharp and everything was fine but I want to use httpclient. Here is the code:

```
public async Task<User> AddUser(string email)
{
    var url = "user/";
    _client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myWeb.com/");
    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(Constants."application/json"));
    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    var json = new {email = email }
    var response = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync(url,json);
    if (response .IsSuccessStatusCode)
    { ....
```

Here is the constructor:

```
private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

public UserRepository(HttpClient httpClient)
{         
    _httpClient = httpClient;
}
```

Method calling:

```
var user1 = AddUser("user@user.com");
var user2 = AddUser("test@test.com");

await Task.WhenAll(user1, user2);
```

and here is the startup configuation:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

So what am I doing wrong? Do I need to change AddSingleton with AddTransient() or is there any other issue. One more question do I need to use _client.Dispose() after the response because the tutorial which I followed didn't use dispose method so I am little confused in that.

Comment: Don't change the base address and default headers every call

Comment: Should I add baseaddress in startup?

Comment: Is there a reason your singleton is `<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>` instead of just `<HttpClient>`?

Comment: Yeah, In that way I was getting this error: "Unable to resolve service for type '' while attempting to activate '"

Comment: You might want to look at [Flurl](https://flurl.io/). It makes everything from request-level headers to bearer tokens to HttpClient singleton management a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

`HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders` (and `BaseAddress`) should only be set once, before you make any requests. `HttpClient` is only safe to use as a singleton if you don't modify it once it's in use.

Rather than setting `DefaultRequestHeaders`, set the headers on each `HttpRequestMessage` you are sending.

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
request.Headers.Accept.Clear();
request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
request.Content = new StringContent("{...}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await _client.SendAsync(request, CancellationToken.None);
```

Replace `"{...}"` with your JSON.

Comment: That's all good but I'm really stuck on Cookies.  They aren't super common on hitting APIs but sometimes needed on scraping.  So, I want to control the cookie container and set it to a new one with some requests.  This seems impossible if we want to reuse HttpClient

Comment: @GarrGodfrey disabling cookies per-request is possible, but having a separate cookie container for a set of requests requires having a separate `HttpClient` with a separate `SocketsHttpHandler`, so you won't be able to use a singleton `HttpClient` in this case anyway. You may be able to pool this with `IHttpClientFactory`. If you want a more detailed answer then please ask a separate question.

Comment: It fails changing value of `UseCookies` after first use with same error as changing `BaseAddress`.   HttpClient may just be more trouble than it is worth.

Answer (score 18):

Maybe my two cents will help someone.

I ran into this issue when refreshing the page when debugging the application.

I was using a singleton, but each refresh, it was trying to set the base address. So I just wrapped it in a check to see if the base address had already been set.

The issue for me was, it was trying to set the baseAddress, even though it was already set. You can't do this with a httpClient.

```
if (_httpClient.BaseAddress == null)
{
    _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
}
```

Comment: This actually helped me a lot, it was exactly what I was facing.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is caused by resetting BaseAddress  and headers for the same instance of the httpclient.

I tried

```
if (_httpClient.BaseAddress == null)
```

but I am not keen on this.

In my opinion, a better soloution is to use the httpclientFactory. This will terminate and garbage collect the instance of the httpclient after its use.

```
private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
public Foo (IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory) 
{
_httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
}
public  httpresponse Bar ()
{
_httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient(command.ClientId);

using var response = await _httpclient.PostAsync(uri,content);
return response;
// here as there is no more reference to the _httpclient, the garbage collector will clean 
// up the _httpclient and release that instance. Next time the method is called a new 
// instance of the _httpclient is created
}
```

Comment: Love the use of a factory here.  Should note that it requires dependency injection though, which may not fit all use cases.

Answer (score 4):

It Works well when you add the request url and the headers at the message, rather than at the client. So better not to assign to `BaseAddress` Or the header `DefaultRequestHeaders` if you will use them for many requests.

```
HttpRequestMessage msg = new HttpRequestMessage {
    Method = HttpMethod.Put,
    RequestUri = new Uri(url),
    Headers = httpRequestHeaders;
};

httpClient.SendAsync(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has sometime now but, I just hit this issue trying to call a client within a  `Parallel.ForEachAsync` loop.

Solved based on the answer by [Mali Tbt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63550624/8015237)

Just injected `IHttpClientFactory` in the constructor, and used it to create a client instances on each iteration.

Applying to OP case:

```
private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

// Constructor
public UserRepository(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
  {         
      _clientFactory = httpClientFactory;
  }

// calling method
public async Task<User> AddUser(string email)
{
    var url = "user/";
    var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("UserRepository");

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myWeb.com/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(Constants."application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    var json = new {email = email }
    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url,json);
    if (response .IsSuccessStatusCode)
    { ....
```