# xamarin.forms httpclient change BaseAddress multiple times runtime

Tags: xamarin.forms, httpclient

I have updated my Xamarin.Forms to latest Version (4.5.0.530).
After that I cannot change the BaseAddress of my httpclient.
I have the following Code:

```
private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());
client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(App.hostserveradress);
client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
```

Later, after I called the Webservice with:

```
responseReset = await client.PostAsync("GetResetFotos", contentReset);
```

I want to change the BaseAddress to another:

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(App.serveradress);
```

But when I set thew new BaseAddress I get following error:

```
This instance has already started one or more requests. Properties can only be modified before sending the first request.
```

Before the updating Xamarin.Forms everything works perfect, now I get the named error.

What can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders and BaseAddress)  should only be set once before you make any requests.

Comment: Okay, but why did it work before the update ?
What can I now do, that I can call two different BaseAddresses on runtime?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51478525/httpclient-this-instance-has-already-started-one-or-more-requests-properties-ca

Comment: Ah okay, so I have to create an HttpRequestMessage?
But why did that changed?

Comment: You don't NEED to set a base address. If you simply use full URLs, you can make requests to as many sites as you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You don't NEED to set a base address. If you simply use full URLs, you
>   can make requests to as many sites as you want.

This solved my problem thanks @PaulVrugt